# CSS style element optimization logic

Tags: html, css, optimization

### Problem

Some process is generating HTML file**s** (more than one) with style elements (containing CSS) that may appear anywhere (even outside head elements). Please ignore for a moment that this is non-standard, in this case it is intended (and not a bug).

### Objective

The target is to post-process the aforementioned HTML files to make it valid or more performant.

The first step is to "pull" up all these style elements into the head element (to make the HTML valid). This is very easy to do (I'm using a DOM manipulation library).

The next step is extract common CSS into a shared external CSS file. This part is where it gets tricky: it's possible that by extracting all shared styles, either the non-shared or the external ones might overwrite each other (hopefully the example below is more clear).

#### After step 1

###### (assume all styles have been moved to head in the same order)

**test1.html**

```html
..
<head>
    <style> h1 { color: red } </style>
    <style> h2 { color: blue } </style>
    <style> h3 { color: green } </style>
</head>
..
```

**test2.html**

```html
..
<head>
    <style> h1 { color: red } </style>
    <style> h2 { color: purple } h3 { color: yellow } </style>
    <style> h3 { color: green } </style>
    <!-- NOTE: h3 will be effectively green -->
</head>
..
```

#### After step 2

**shared.css**

```css
    h1 { color: red }
    h3 { color: green }
```

**test1.html**

```html
..
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared.css">
    <style> h2 { color: blue } </style>
</head>
..
```

**test2.html**

```html
..
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared.css">
    <style> h2 { color: purple } h3 { color: yellow } </style>
    <!-- NOTE: h3 will now be yellow, but it should have been green -->
</head>
..
```

---

I hope the example makes sense. The question is, is there any good way to avoid mangling up the rules' order while still being able to optimise it?

I can see these two solutions so far:

1. only extract shared CSS until the first block that is not common anymore (e.g. in the example above, only h1 will be shared).
2. pass the entire documents' CSS through a parser that generates the effective CSS, somehow figuring out and removing declarations that have been overridden while also keeping the overriding ones unshared.

Comment: I don't think there's a smart way to it: remember that CSS cascades, so when your selector gets complicated there is no way you can intelligently merge the styles. In all honestly this sounds like an issue you should've fixed _at the source_ with a build step or a proper preprocessor, and not on the client-side at runtime.

Comment: It's not done on the client side...this _is_ a preprocessor. Maybe I could have just asked how to implement a CSS preprocesor. :D

Comment: On the other hand, how would you imagine it to work at an earlier stage?
If the page contains component `Header1`, `Header2` and `Header3` the CSS of each will have to be loaded in some specific order anyway, and build systems typically do end up with shared (external) styles and a page-specific one (in-page).